# Working with multiple parameter packs to convert runtime values into compile template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

On my first venture into variadic templates I'm trying to create a function that instantiates a derived class with all combinations of template arguments. The idea being to have a runtime options class be able to select the exact template instantiation to use. I've been able to get the base-case to work with 1 and 2 template arguments. But the general case is not working, the third invocation of SelectInstance below fails to compile with the following error:

> candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
>   AbstractBase *SelectInstance(Func func, Args... args)

The complete code is the following:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Options
{
  bool GetFirstParameter() { return true; }
  bool GetSecondParameter() { return false; }
  bool GetThirdParameter() { return true; }
};

struct AbstractBase
{
  virtual void PrintMe() = 0;
};

template<class... Args>
struct Derived : public AbstractBase
{
  virtual void PrintMe() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

template<class... Args>
AbstractBase *SelectInstance()
{
  return new Derived<Args...>();
}

template<class Func, class... UnpackedArgs>
AbstractBase *SelectInstance(Func func)
{
  if (func())
    return SelectInstance<float, UnpackedArgs...>();
  else
    return SelectInstance<double, UnpackedArgs...>();
}

template<class Func, class... Args, class... UnpackedArgs>
AbstractBase *SelectInstance(Func func, Args... args)
{
  if (func())
    return SelectInstance<Args...,  float, UnpackedArgs...>(args...);
  else
    return SelectInstance<Args..., double, UnpackedArgs...>(args...);
}

int main()
{
  Options opts;
  std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase> one(
    SelectInstance(
      std::bind(&Options::GetFirstParameter, &opts)
      )
    );
  one->PrintMe();

  std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase> two(
    SelectInstance(
      std::bind(&Options::GetFirstParameter, &opts),
      std::bind(&Options::GetSecondParameter, &opts)
      )
    );
  two->PrintMe();

  // this one fails to compile!
  std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase> three(
    SelectInstance(
      std::bind(&Options::GetFirstParameter, &opts),
      std::bind(&Options::GetSecondParameter, &opts),
      std::bind(&Options::GetThirdParameter, &opts)
      )
    );
  three->PrintMe();
}
```

I'm probably misusing the variadic templates improperly to convert functors into a new parameter pack. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your attempt fails is that the compiler can't tell which arguments you're providing for what. Let's say our function types are `A`, `B`, and `C` for simplicity. The initial call is:

```
// Func = A, Args... = {B, C}, UnpackedArgs... = {}
AbstractBase *SelectInstance(Func func, Args... args)
```

From here, we call `SelectInstance<Args...,  float, UnpackedArgs...>(args...);` Which is to say, `SelectInstance<B, C, float>(b, c);` You're intending that to mean:

```
// Func = B, Args... = {C}, UnpackedArgs... = {float}
AbstractBase *SelectInstance(Func func, Args... args)
```

but really parameter packs are greedy and take everything. `Args...` takes every subsequent type argument you explicitly provide. So really that call is interpreted as:

```
// Func = B, Args... = {C, float}, UnpackedArgs... = {}
AbstractBase *SelectInstance(Func func, Args... args)
```

This function takes three arguments (a `B`, a `C`, and a `float`) but you're only passing two (`b` and `c`), hence the error.

---

To fix this, flip the ordering of your template arguments to put the **non** deduced ones first, and the deduced ones last. This way, you can still use template deduction to do the right thing and even avoid an extra overload:

```
template<class... Args>
AbstractBase *SelectInstance()
{
  return new Derived<Args...>();
}

template<class... UnpackedArgs, class Func, class... Args>
AbstractBase *SelectInstance(Func func, Args... args)
{
  if (func()) {
    return SelectInstance<float, UnpackedArgs...>(args...);
  }
  else {
    return SelectInstance<double, UnpackedArgs...>(args...);
  }
}
```

This works because now all the arguments you provide go into `UnpackedArgs...` and deduction figures out `Func` and `Args...` - which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Once I wrote that extra overload, I felt like I was going down the wrong path. Note, I flipped this to "SelectInstance<UnpackedArgs..., T>" to keep the order of the unpacking the same as the functor passed in as arguments.